# Fundamental difference between Generic Principal and Forms Authentication in context of ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, forms, generics, authentication, principal

What exactly is the difference between Forms Authentication and Generic Principal? If I use Forms Authentication in ASP.NET, what advantage would I have by implementing the Generic Principal  as well as Generic Identity over not implementing these? This is assuming that they are 2 different approaches to the same thing.

However, if they are not 2 different approaches to the same thing, then what exactly does Generic Principal provide for us that Forms Authentication alone does not?

Answer (score 2):

Generic principal lets you store information about your user in objects that you can then bind to Context.User. This means that rather than run to the database every time to get information, it can be stored in session. This doesn't really relate to forms authentication, which is simply a way of signing users in and out and keeping their sign in inside of a cookie.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What can i do or what advantage do i have if i bind an object to Context.User? I still dont understand under what scenario would I want to implement a Generic Principal (in other words, why isnt forms authentication sufficient?) The reason I ask is because I have seen a number of tutorials that also implement Generic Principal with Forms Authentication and a number of tutorials that do not. What then is the difference?

Comment: for example, have a look at this article http://www.15seconds.com/issue/041208.htm. Go down to the ASP.NET authentication section and you would see that the writer is using forms authentication and then in the global.asax Application_AuthenticateRequest they are creating a new Generic Principal.

Why is a new Generic Principal being created in Application_AuthenticateRequest when the application would work just as well without creating it. Plus, if I am not mistaken, Forms authentication also creates a Generic Principal in its implementation and associates to httpcontext.current.user.